# Setting a key prop on a component

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm trying to set a key prop on a react component but I don't know why I get the following error

> "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop"

This is the code where I set the key to the element

```
var lists = this.props.lists.map(listName => {
      return (
        <List key={listName.id} title={listName} cards={['Card1']} onAddClick={console.log('Clicked')}/>
      )
    })
```

I really don't know what can be happening here, any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you 100% certain the list doesn't contain two items that have the same `.id`?

Comment: What is `listName`? Is it an object? It seems it is a string `title={listName} `

Comment: lists is a prop I pass like lists={['List1', 'List2']}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listName` is a string. It doesn't have `id` property. All `listName.id` results in same value `undefined`

If they are unique you can use listName as a key.

```
var lists = this.props.lists.map(listName => {
      return (
        <List key={listName} title={listName} cards={['Card1']} onAddClick={console.log('Clicked')}/>
      )
    })
```

Comment: listName is not a 100% guarantee to work as a key. What happens if the data contains multiple items with the same listName? Index should be used like in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`listName` and therefore doesn't have an id value that you're trying to set as a key. Since `listName` is also a string, there is no guarantee that it will be 100% unique. In order to fix this, do something like the following :

```
var lists = this.props.lists.map((listName, index) => {
  return (
    <List key={index} title={listName} cards={['Card1']} onAddClick={console.log('Clicked')}/>
  )
});
```